# Quicksort in C with huge amount of data / memory

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I have the following code setup:

```
#define TSIZE 32
#define TNUM 24000000
#define CORES 4

/* Byte-wise swap two items of size SIZE. */
#define SWAP(a, b, size)                    \
  do                                        \
    {                                       \
      size_t __size = (size);               \
      char *__a = (a), *__b = (b);          \
      do                                    \
      {                                     \
        char __tmp = *__a;                  \
        *__a++ = *__b;                      \
        *__b++ = __tmp;                     \
      } while (--__size > 0);               \
  } while (0)

char* TWEETS;

size_t partition(void* arr, size_t left, size_t right, int (*compar)(const void* , const void*))
{
    char* cArr = (char*) arr;

    size_t i;
    size_t pivotIndex = (left+right)/2;
    char* pivotValue = &cArr[(size_t)TSIZE * right];
    size_t index = left;

    SWAP(&cArr[(size_t)TSIZE * pivotIndex], &cArr[(size_t)TSIZE * right], (size_t)TSIZE);

    for(i = left; i < right; i++) {
        if(compar((void*) &cArr[(size_t)TSIZE * i], (void*) pivotValue) < 0) {
            SWAP(&cArr[(size_t)TSIZE * i], &cArr[(size_t)TSIZE * index], (size_t)TSIZE);
            index++;
        }
    }
    SWAP(&cArr[(size_t)TSIZE * index], &cArr[(size_t)TSIZE * right], (size_t)TSIZE);
    return index;
}

void quicksort(void* base, size_t left, size_t right, int (*compar)(const void* , const void*))
{
    if(left < right) {
        size_t pivot = partition(base, left, right, compar);

        #pragma omp task
        quicksort(base, left, pivot-1, compar);

        #pragma omp task
        quicksort(base, pivot+1, right, compar);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(CORES);
    TWEETS = (char*) malloc((size_t)TNUM * (size_t)TSIZE * (size_t)CORES * (size_t)sizeof(char));
    if(TWEETS == NULL) exit(1);

    readData();

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        quicksort(TWEETS, 0, ((size_t)CORES*(size_t)TNUM)-(size_t)1, compare);
    }

    free(TWEETS);
}
```

So first of all, forgive the huge amount of (size_t) casts, I did this in a fit of desperation.

**What am I doing here**
I am reading in a text file with 24 million lines of text, each line contains 32 bytes of characters. The lines are then sorted according to the compare function, which I have omitted here. I can guarantee that this function works and is not the cause of my trouble. At all times it returns either -1, 0 or 1.
I am also trying to parallelize the quicksort algorithm. The lines of code grow along with the amount of cores I use, e.g. 1 core = 24million, 2 cores = 48 million and so on.

**What is working already**
Working already is sorting the file with 1 to 8 cores as long as the file size stays below 48 million lines of text.

**What is my problem**
My problem is that, once I try to sort a file with 72 million lines of text or more the quicksort algorithm runs into a segmentation fault. I have debugged the code with gdb as far as I could, and the code that is at fault is this line:

```
SWAP(&cArr[(size_t)TSIZE * i], &cArr[(size_t)TSIZE * index], (size_t)TSIZE);
```

It's the swap call in the partition function in the for loop. I could also see that, at this point, the variable "right" had the value 18446744073709551615 (2^64-1) which is the cause of the segmentation fault. The maximum value "right" should ever have is TSIZE * TNUM * CORES. Since the number is that huge my only guess is that an overflow happens somewhere in the algorithm.

And well, here's the catch: The algorithm and the entire program work flawlessly when staying <= 48 million lines of text. Once I go beyond that the segfault happens. I have also made sure that reading in the data works, meaning after the process of reading in the data about 3gb of my RAM are in use. The segfault definitely occurs during the sorting of the char array.

So why is it working with up to 48.000.000 lines of text, and why is it segfaulting when having more than that? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Could it be because you add left and right before dividing by 2, overflow?

Comment: And in respect to that, try `left + (right - left)/2` (which you should do even if it is *not* your problem).

Comment: @WhozCraig That was the right expression, was trying to find a definitive source for it.

Comment: It's unlikely that (left+right)/2 is the cause of the problem, since the segfault happens at the swap in the for loop which is not using the pivotIndex.  Thanks for the suggestion WhozCraig.

Comment: Each line is 32 bytes, so you're reading in a total of 2.304 GB. If your program is 32-bit then it probably can't access more than 2.147 GB.

Comment: @Roter_Fuchs But did you try replacing that expression? And btw, is `size_t` signed?

Comment: If I couldn't read in more than 2.147GB then the segfault would happen during reading the data in. Reading it in though is working successfully. I have monitored my RAM usage during execution and, when reading in 96million lines of text it grew to about 3.5gb usage, so everything should be fine there. I also have a 64-bit system and compiled the program accordingly.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen I haven't tried replacing that expression yet. size_t is unsigned.

Comment: Any chance you are running into a stack limit?  If the partitioning goes badly, you could end up using all your stack space.

Comment: dont do big sorts with quicksort. it has terrible memory access characteristics. If you want to do really big sorts read up on the way dbms's do it because theyre super efficient at it.

Comment: I think @LasseV.Karlsen has the answer, but you should also consider swapping a list of string *pointers* instead of the actual strings themselves. That will make your code run considerably faster — pointers can be swapped with just 3 processor opcodes, while your `SWAP` macro will require dozens.

Comment: Another easy and very important optimization is to only recurse on the smaller partition.

Comment: this algorithm will be painfully slow for such a large number of items to be sorted.  A much better 'tweak' of the algorithm is to generate a doubly linked list of pointers to each item to be sorted, then only the entries in the doubly linked list are manipulated so the final doubly linked list (of which no nodes are moved, only the next prev pointers are modified).  It will take more (virtual) ram which can slow things down some, but not near as much as moving the actual items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an edge case in your algorithm that isn't accounted for.

If the bottom (left edge) partition of the *original* sequence *ever* encounters *no swaps* (i.e. every value is "greater-or-equal" than the pivot), then `index` , which started out at zero (`0`), will remain as such. The index `i` will march to the end. The pivot value that your temporarily storing in the right-most slot is then swapped into place (i.e. `cArr[0]` and `cArr[right]` are swapped), and you return `0` from the function. In other words, this:

```
size_t pivot = partition(base, left, right, compar);

#pragma omp task
quicksort(base, left, pivot-1, compare);
// here ================^
```

executes with`pivot` being returned as zero from the prior call, passes `pivot-1` as `right` and results in an underflow. This would give you *exactly* the value of `right` you're getting when you fault. (2^64-1 on every platform I've ever used).

You need to account for this (or never let it happen in the first place). Whether this happens in your code is entirely dependent on the content of each partition that is processed with `left=0`. It may not happen the first time, the second time, etc.. But get the right data swapped into that continually decreasing  partition space and eventually it can happen.

---

**Untested, But Worth A Look**

I'm not a fan of `left` and `right` partitioning markers in C-implementations of quicksort() in the first place. The language supports pointer math, so use *that* and tout around something you know is concrete (a base and a length). I've not tested the following, and have only once ever had to deal with OMP, but simplified, what I mean is something like this:

```
void quicksort(void* base, size_t len, int(*compar)(const void*, const void*))
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    char* cArr = (char*)base;
    char* pivotValue = cArr + ((size_t)TSIZE * (len - 1));
    SWAP(cArr + ((size_t)TSIZE * (len / 2)), pivotValue, TSIZE);

    size_t i;
    size_t pivot = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (compar(cArr + ((size_t)TSIZE * i), ) < 0)
        {
            SWAP(cArr + ((size_t)TSIZE * i), cArr + ((size_t)TSIZE * pivot), (size_t)TSIZE);
            ++pivot;
        }
    }
    SWAP(cArr + ((size_t)TSIZE * pivot), pivotValue, (size_t)TSIZE);

#pragma omp task
    quicksort(cArr, pivot++, compar);

#pragma omp task
    quicksort(cArr+((size_t)TSIZE * pivot), len-pivot, compar);
}
```

I hope it is obvious how this is called.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately I am not able to test this right now, as I don't have the necessary data and hardware with me. Once I can I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: @Roter_Fuchs no worries. Sorry if the sample doesn't work out of the gate (I don't know omp and have nothing I can test this on at-hand) But, I hope you understand the idea. using base, len, and pointer math really is the way to do this if you have the chance, though for you the likely simplest work-around is `if(pivot > 0)` before your first recursion.

Comment: I was able to give it a try and it was really the edge case you described which was at fault. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The one pass partition operation is simple and cute, but it does **much** more swapping than it needs to.   As written, in a little test I found it does **two-and-a-half times** as many swaps as required !

There are two issues with the 'cute' partition:

1. when `index` and `i` are the same, and the value is < pivot value, then it does a swap of itself to itself.  If the swap is expensive, then a test for "self" will save a little.
2. when it swaps, it is moving the value at the `index` forwards to `i`, and stepping both.  If the `index` arrives at the value, it may have to swap it forwards again -- doing "extra" (unnecessary) swaps, to shuffle values along ahead of the advancing `index'.

Consider partitioning five values: `9 3 5 1 4`.  First, 5 will be chosen as the pivot-value, and swapped with the 4, giving `9 3 4 1 5`.  Then, starting with `index == i == left`, the 9 is greater than the pivot, so leave `index` and advance `i`.  Now 3 is less than the pivot, so we swap 9 and 3 and advance both `index` and `i`, giving `3 9 4 1 5`.  Now 4 is less than the pivot, so swap **again**, shuffling the 9 forwards, giving `3 4 9 1 5`.  And 1 is also less than the pivot, so swap **again**, giving `3 4 1 9 5`.  Finally, swapping the pivot value into place completes the process to give `3 4 1 5 9`.

So, this does **3** swaps to shuffle the 9 along, where only **1** swap is required.

A common, but less simple, way of doing the partition scans first from the left and then from the right, looking for values that need to be swapped up and down, so that the process is done in the minimum number of swaps.

I tried this for vectors of 50 integers, each value selected at random from 1..50.  I ran the 'cute' partition and a more 'Traditional' one, and counted the swaps over 20,000 trials.  I got:

```
Average 'trad' swaps  =  9.8
Average 'cute' swaps  = 23.0
Average 'cute' selfs  =  2.9
Average 'cute' extra  = 13.0
```

where 'trad' minimises the number of swaps.  The "selfs" is swaps where `index` == `i`, and `extras` are where a value is swapped forward more than once.  The 'cute' swaps count includes the 'extras', but not the 'selfs' (because the 'selfs' are trivial to eliminate).

The swap counts include swapping out the pivot value and swapping it back in again -- because those are the same for both algorithms.  Discounting those two swaps, the 'cute' algorithm is doing 23.9/7.8 or *three times* as many swaps as are required (on average, on my little test).

So, however cute it is, the simple, one pass partition is rubbish.

---

For completeness, here is a more "traditional" partition:

```
  /* 'left' and 'right' are indexes into 'data', and there are
   * are 'right' - 'left' + 1 items in the partition.
   *
   * 'pivot' is the index of the chosen pivot-value, and is set
   * to the (new) index for that when the partition completes.
   */
  pv = data[pivot] ;

  swap(data, pivot, right) ;

  l = left ;
  r = right ;

  while (l < r)
    {
      --r ;

      while ((l < r) && (data[l] <= pv))
        ++l ;

      while ((l < r) && (data[r] >= pv))
        --r ;

      if (l == r)
        {
          if (data[r] < pv)
            ++r ;
          break ;
        } ;

      swap(data, l, r) ;

      ++l ;
    } ;

  pivot = r ;

  swap(data, pivot, right) ;
```